# QT HTTP Server with Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, http

I write a simple HTTP server which get a PUT request process it and return a answer. Everything is ok when I read the text of request but when i write back the response I get a warning like this ***QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QNativeSocketEngine(0x7fffe0003950), parent's thread is Htt(0x7fffffffe6f0), current thread is QThread(0x6128b0)***
The code for server

```
    #include "Htt.h"

Htt::Htt()
{
}


void Htt::run() {
    m_server = new QTcpServer();

    m_server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 56789);

    connect(m_server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), SLOT(ConnectClient()));
    exec();
}


void Htt::ConnectClient() {
    m_client = m_server->nextPendingConnection();
    connect(m_client, SIGNAL(readyRead()), SLOT(CitesteDate()));
}


void Htt::ReadData() {
    QByteArray data = m_client->readAll();

    SendRespond();
}


void Htt::SendRespond() {
    QByteArray codSucces = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n";


    m_client->write(codSucces);
    m_client->close();
}
```

Here is the header for this class

```
#ifndef HTT_H
#define HTT_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>

class Htt : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QTcpServer *m_server;
    QTcpSocket *m_client;


    void SendRespond();

private slots:
    void ConnectClient();

    void ReadData();
public:
    Htt();

    void run();
};

#endif // HTT_H
```

Thank for any help!!!

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874844/writing-data-to-a-tcpsocket-in-own-thread

Comment: I saw it, but I don't understood too much. There I need to create a object of type QThread and move there a client and invoke start of thread, but where is implementation of run method of thread ?

Comment: It's just a hunch. I had this type of error but after I changed QTcpSocket* to QTcpSocket it disappeared. Try changing pointers in class to objects.

Comment: Ok, I will try today and will write the resultat. Thx guys!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you derived from QThread which normally is a mistake.

To be more detailed: Htt instance itself lives in your main thread. So when you create your connections you are connecting objects living in your sub-thread (m_server and m_client) to an object living in the main thread (Htt instance). This is why the connected slots are executed in the main thread and not in the sub-thread. This is why you finally get an error in SendRespond() that complains about being executed in the wrong thread.

Search in SO and the web. You will find a lot of similar questions since what you have done is probably the most common error when using QThread.

Comment: I got you! I derived because for me this variant is most understandable. Now I will create m_client instance after run method was invoked. Thank you for help

Comment: It works fine :) Thanks Silicomancer, you really help me!!! The secret it's just to start server after method run